# Ubuntu loses text-editor focus from time to time

Tags: eclipse, matlab, ubuntu, text-editor, lostfocus

I have just upgraded from Ubuntu 10.04 to 12.04.3 LTS. An annoying thing I discovered is that, in eclipse and matlab, I cannot type text sometimes. The detailed phenomena are as follows:

Eclipse

1. Happens after using auto-completion (activated by customized shortcut `alt+/`), or switching from other windows, or pressing `ctrl+z`, etc.
2. Can use mouse to move cursor around, but keyboard does not respond.
3. Using `alt-tab` to switch back and forth can solve the problem.

And similar things are happening in matlab, whenever I hit `tab` . But `gedit` and browser are working fine. Wonder if anyone has encountered the same problem. Thanks.

Comment: Probably better to move this question to [askubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/). As a bonus, if you open an account there you get 100 extra reputation here ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. It's really a conflict between out-of-date keyboard input methods and java programs in Ubuntu 12.04. See https://askubuntu.com/questions/365205/text-editors-in-eclipse-matlab-loses-focus-occasionally-after-upgrading-to-12-04.